# Zuul ReadTimeout by Service

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I have a Zuul proxy, and it works fine until it redirects to a server that takes longer time than normal (more than 10 seconds) to response.

I can modify the read-timeout through properties (zuul.host.socket-timeout-millis) so it can work properly.

```
ribbon.eureka.enabled=false
zuul.host.connect-timeout-millis=100000
zuul.host.socket-timeout-millis=100000
```

But I need a different timeout based on the service that the proxy is reaching.

**I don't have Eureka in my architecture so I disabled it in the properties. (ribbon.eureka.enabled=false)**

I've tried with

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.timeout.enabled=false
hystrix.command.messages.execution.isolation.strategy=THREAD
hystrix.command.messages.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds= 100000
```

But it doesn't work. It always use the value on zuul.host.socket-timeout-millis and if I don't set this property Zuul, uses a 10 seconds timeout.

I've also tried

```
messages.ribbon.ReadTimeout=120000
ribbon.ReadTimeout=60000
```

But it always use what is on  zuul.host.socket-timeout-millis

I don't know how to set the timeout by service.

So I can set for service1 30 seconds, for service2 45 seconds and for the other services a default of 60.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: no, I think it's not able to do that

Comment: Worked for me:

`zuul.host.connect-timeout-millis=600000`

`zuul.host.socket-timeout-millis=600000`

`hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=600000`

Answer (score -1):

I supose you have but I'll ask: Have you tried configuring both properties at the same time with a higher value?

It should work, we use this feature in Zuul and it works well but you need to configure booth timeouts (Zuul and Ribbon)

You have info about how this works here: [Ribbon](https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon/wiki/Programmers-Guide#client-configuration-options), [Hystrix](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration#executionisolationthreadtimeoutinmilliseconds)

Note that depending on how you use Zuul the name of your client could be different for Ribbon and for Hystrix.